# Should micro-services query the database directly or go through graph ql api?

Tags: graphql, architecture, microservices, system-design

I am asking from a good design point of view.

Should micro-services query the database directly or go through graph ql api? Let say I have something like a step function, should I query MongoDB directly or use graph ql api?

Is this a common or used architecture design?

I am trying to fully understand the use cases of Graph QL.

Comment: This question is soliciting opinions. Typically one would use GraphQL between the microservices and the client(s). It's possible but less common to use GraphQL between microservices and likely very rare to use it between a microservice and a db.

Comment: @MichelFloyd. Thank you. I wanted to understand if it was a common pattern now I undetstand.